# Is it possible to change the default window size of a .txt file in TextEdit?

Tags: macos, textedit, customization

I have a .txt file that I open regularly on my Mac. I would like the TextEdit window of this .txt file to be wider than it normally is.

I can manually increase the window width every time I open the file by left-clicking and dragging the bottom-right corner further to the right. But, it would be much more convenient if the window was wider by default.

---

I have tried adjusting the TextEdit window size while holding down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key.

I have tried adjusting the TextEdit window size while holding down the  <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> key.

I have tried adjusting the TextEdit window size while holding down the <kbd>control</kbd> key.

After quitting TextEdit and then re-opening the .txt file, none of the above methods recall the previously-set window size.

---

I am also open to a method that uses AppleScript to set the window size before the file is opened. Here's the AppleScript command that I currently employ to open the file:

```
do shell script "open -e " & quoted form of Target_Filepath
```

Comment: I've added a note to my answer which provides information surrounding the actual Title Question: "_Is it possible to change the default window size of a .txt file in TextEdit?_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the default windows size, unless you want to make it permanent and you can just change it in TextEdit > Preferences... then, you can use the following example AppleScript *code* to open the document in TextEdit and set its size and position on the screen.

First, open the target file, resize and position it on the screen where you want it and the use the following AppleScript *code* to get the `bounds` of the *document window* to use going forward.

```
tell application "TextEdit" to get bounds of front window
```

It will return a `list`, e.g.: `{0, 22, 900, 600}`, to use with the `set bounds ...` *command*.

```
set targetFile to POSIX path of (path to documents folder) & "Filename.txt"

tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    open targetFile
    set bounds of front window to {0, 22, 900, 600}
end tell
```

---

Note: The reason I'm suggesting the above method is because while one can technically change the default size of the document window programmatically nonetheless since TextEdit doesn't support a `position` *property* it makes sense to use the `bounds` *property* as the first two *list items* in the `bounds` *property*  are its position.

However, if you really want to change the default size prior to opening the target document regardless of it position, here is the information surrounding the default window size. Under TextEdit > Preferences... > New Document > Window Size the default Width is 90 characters and the default Height is 30 lines. With these defaults there are no *keys* in the `com.apple.TextEdit.plist` file for this however the corresponding *keys* are `WidthInChars` and `HeightInChars`, which support an *integer* value.

You'd need to test for the existence of these *keys* and capture their values so as to have something to reset to after opening the target document. If they are the true defaults, the *keys* will not exist and you can temporarily set a *integer* value for these *keys*, open the target document and then delete the *keys*. The target document window will open with the new values at the default location of TextEdit's choice, not yours. If you want it in a different location you'd need to use `set bounds ...`, which defeats programmatically temporarily changing the defaults or the existing setting if not the default values.

Example *code* using the `defaults` *command*:

```
defaults read $HOME/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist WidthInChars
defaults read $HOME/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist HeightInChars

defaults write $HOME/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist WidthInChars -int 120
defaults write $HOME/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist HeightInChars -int 50

defaults delete $HOME/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist WidthInChars
defaults delete $HOME/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist HeightInChars
```

These can be used in a `do shell script` *command* using `set variableName to do shell script "defaults read ..."` and then write the *logic flow* based on what's returned.

If you really want to go this route and need help with the coding, let me know.

Also note that testing surrounding this was done under macOS 10.12 and may be different in previous major OS version releases.

Comment: The first method works. Thank you. Using the first method, there is a slight delay while the window size adjusts, but that is not a huge deal; I don't think this minor delay is worth the effort to implement the second method.

Comment: Strangely enough, I've discovered that if you open an .rtf file in TextEdit, adjust the window size, and then save the .rtf file, TextEdit will recall your window size the next time this file is opened. This does not apply to .txt files for some reason. Also, the location of the window of an .rtf file is fixed and is not recalled after saving the file.

Comment: @rubik's sphere, I did my testing using a plain text file having a `.txt` extension because that is what you had in your question. The info about a Rich Text .`rtf` file is interesting but really has no bering on your original question or my answer as it was not part of the question to begin with.

Comment: Yes, I know. It wasn't really related to my question. I just thought that it was strange that .rtf files remember the previous window size, but .txt files do not.